# Unlist into a new dataframe but replicate ID

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I am new to learning coding and stackoverflow and am struggling with the following:

```
ID
1
2
3


ITEMS
c(a,b,c)
a
b
```

I want a new dataframe that will output the following

```
ID
1
1
1
2
3

ITEMS
a
b
c
a
b
```

So I want to effectively unlist my ITEMS column but at the same time replicating/matching my ID column.

Comment: Please add data using `dput` and show the expected output for the same. Read about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: Try `df1 <- tidyr::unnest(df, ITEMS)`

Comment: @RonakShah Thank you very much. I will also read up on how to frame good questions as you suggest. Thanks again.